# What is a good comprehensive maths book?

Tags: reference-request, self-learning, book-recommendation

I'm currently studying electrical engineering at university and keep running into issues where I've missed, forgotten or never correctly learnt the required maths.

I'm looking for a book that covers most to all maths for a moderate university level. I've tried to look myself for a book however reviews for maths books are relatively limited and as the books are a (relatively) large investment I was wondering if there are any good recommendations.

Comment: "All the Mathematics You Missed But Need to Know for Graduate School" by T. A. Garitty

Comment: First suggestion: don't invest.  Surely your university would have relevant books in a library?  As to which books, if you're studying engineering I would search the catalogue for anything entitled "engineering mathematics".  We used Kreyszig when I was an undergrad... but that was a long time ago :)